# Laravel Eloquent select distinct from relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between categories and products tables.

```
┌─────────────────┐          ┌─────────────────┐          ┌──────────────────┐
│ categories      │          │ products        │          │ category_product │
├─────────────────┤          ├─────────────────┤          ├──────────────────┤
| id              |          | id              |          | shop_id          |
| name            |          | name            |          | category_id      |
| created_at      |          | price           |          | product_id       |
└─────────────────┘          | created_at      |          | created_at       |
                             └─────────────────┘          └──────────────────┘
```

Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Because I'm using the cetegory_product table to also map the shop. I have some problem with getting the distinct results. let's just say that I have the following records in the pivot table:

```
shop_id  |  category_id  |  product_id
--------------------------------------
1        |18             |4
1        |18             |5
```

Now when I try to get the categories for a shop or the reverse relationship like this:

```
$shop = Shop::find(1);
$shop->categories()->get();
```

I get duplicated data.
So I like to know how can I perform a distinct select for categories?

BTW: I tried to add a scope on each model, adding the distinct to the query, but it did not work.

Comment: Maybe you can utilize whereHas for this work around, something like this: `Shop::whereHas('categories', function($q){ return $q->distinct() })->where('id', 1);`

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 shop has many to many relationships just like the others with categories and products nothing is different!

Comment: also many-to-many not hasMany. so use **groupBy('category_id')** instead of **distinct()**

Comment: Sorry! Still no answers.

Comment: I have no idea why? But it seems like eloquent is getting the sql query wrong. because it does not work at all.

Comment: that's weird, I did something like that before

Comment: I did not think it was possible to have a 3-way many-to-many relationship using generated tables. Instead, I have always used a custom model for the joining table on such relationships. Are you sure this is possible the way you're approaching it?

Comment: higher arity or as you called it 3-way many-to-many is not something wrong. it is just so rare. Think of it this way what do you do when you have 3 tables or models associated with each other?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something you should be able to use `groupBy()`.

```
$shop = Shop::find(1);
$shop->categories()->groupBy('category_id')->get();
```

Comment: I get this error for group by : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ...

Comment: In your `config/database.php` add `'strict'    => false` to your `mysql` connections array.

Comment: thanks for answering. It works! BUT don't you think I'm fixing the issue with degrading the security? I think that's not the way to do it even though it worked.

Comment: turning strict mode off will disable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` constraint that comes on by default starting with mysql 5.7 (this was disabled in 5.6 and before)  If you want to fine tune this to ONLY disable that constraint you can override the strict settings with a `modes` array in the config as shown here https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2#customizing-which-modes-are-enabled

Comment: thanks @Eric I think this might be the solution after all!

Answer (score -1):

```
$shop->categories()->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: $shop->categories()->distinct()->get();
and does you set the relation in shop model?

Comment: can you paste the relation in the shop model?